# Should mental-health be a distinct tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should there be a [mental-health](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-health) tag? It was inspired by asking [this question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/16594/explaining-mental-illness-to-children), but could also apply to some others that I've seen...

- [Is watching a moving fan equally harmful to an infant's mental development as is a TV?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8665/is-watching-a-moving-fan-equally-harmful-to-an-infants-mental-development-as-is)
- [Does daycare mentally damage children under three?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7624/does-daycare-mentally-damage-children-under-three)
- [Getting a good diagnosis for possible mental issues?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/6414/getting-a-good-diagnosis-for-possible-mental-issues)

EDIT: Based on Joe's comment below, [I have created it](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tags/mental-health/info), but some attention to its wiki would not go amiss :)

Comment: I see no reason why not - you should have enough rep to create it, I say go ahead!  If you want help finding/retagging i'm happy to help.